Linux: file locking from python script which is running inside docker container
Current situtation:
I am running a docker container on a WAGO PFC200 PLC (custom embedded linux firmware).
The container runs a python script which collects systeminfo like cpu load, memory usage etc. and writes that to a .json-File. This process repeats after 3 seconds in an infinite while-loop.
The file is written to a created subdirectory of the container filesystem "/app/out" which is mounted to "/tmp" of the linux filesystem.
Goal
Open and read the json-File cyclically from a program running in the codesys runtime environment on the controller.
Problem
When opening the .json-File, there are times when the json-File is syntactically incorrect. This occurs while testing the PLC-programm in the Codesys IDE as well as when the file is openend from the filebrowser of mobaXterm (FTP file browser). The problem did never occour however when i openened the file within an SSH-Session with NANO.
3 examples of incorrect files:
{
    "Operating System": "Linux",
    "CPU Load": 26.0,
    "CPU Average Load (1, 5, 15 minutes)": [
        1.48828125,
        2.6689453125,
        2.6484375
    ],
    "Total RAM": 512839680,
    "Used RAM": 99794944,
    "Shared RAM": 3022848,
    "Total Swap Size": 0,
    "Available Swap Size": 0
}e": 0
}

{
    "Operating System": "Linux",
    "CPU Load": 14.9,
    "CPU Average Load (1, 5, 15 minutes)": [
        1.5234375,
        1.2978515625,
        1.8134765625
    ],
    "Total RAM": 512839680,
    "Used RAM": 96014336,
    "Shared RAM": 3035136,
    "Total Swap Size": 0,
    "Available Swap Size": 0
} 0
}

{
    "Operating System": "Linux",
    "CPU Load": 32.0,
    "CPU Average Load (1, 5, 15 minutes)": [
        1.1513671875,
        1.2685546875,
        1.265625
    ],
    "Total RAM": 512839680,
    "Used RAM": 98611200,
    "Shared RAM": 3125248,
    "Total Swap Size": 0,
    "Available Swap Size": 0
}": 0
}

*My observations

The incorrect files always have a part of the end of the json itself added to them (e.g. "e": 0
}")

This error always is accompanied by a long loading time and loading screen:
enter image description here

It happens around every 5-10th time when opening the file


My guess
It seems to have smth to do with the file being written to at the same time it is opened and read.
What i have already tried

Adding "fctnl" to python script

def write_to_json(data, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        try:
            # Acquire an exclusive lock on the file
            print("Acquiring lock...")
            fcntl.flock(file, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
            print("Lock acquired.")

            # Write the system information to the file
            json.dump(data, file, indent=4)

            # Ensure data is written to disk
            file.flush()
            os.fsync(file.fileno())
        finally:
            # Release the lock
            print("Releasing lock...")
            fcntl.flock(file, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
            print("Lock released.")


trying to log the operations on the file with strace

trying to log the operations of "flock" console command


Result

The "debug"-prints ("Acquiring lock...", etc.)  all appear in the container console cyclically

The problem still persists

strace only shows open, read, write, etc. but not locking

I cant use "auditd" instead bc it is not installed and i cannot install new packages


My questions

Is there any other way to trace file locking operations to exmine if the fcntl of the script even works ?

Can it even work because the file is written into the mounted directory and the python script doesnt "reach" the linux filesystem with its call?

Is there any other way to restrict the file being read and written to at the same time (if this is even the problem) ?

What other causes could lead to the shown behaviour ?


Thanks in advance for your answers!
I hope I have added all necessary information. Please let me know if you need the actual code or anything else.

I am not deeply familiar with python or many of what you mentioned. This is something that I suddenly thought of. Why don't you try making the file read only outside of docker? Won't this prevent any change in the content of the file from outside?

Trying to share files between containers can be tricky.  On a native-Linux host not running Docker Desktop I'd probably expect file locking to work, but it wouldn't be my preferred approach.  Can you wrap this setup in a lightweight server (maybe using Flask) and use network requests to retrieve it?  If this script needs to retrieve host-level information, can it successfully run in a container at all, and if not, do you have the same problems if you run it directly on the host?

Don't update the file in place.
Write to temporary file, and then rename it when you're done. Renaming a file is an atomic operation, so the application reading it will always see consistent data.
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".", mode="w") as fd:
    json.dump(mydata, fd)
    os.rename(fd.name, "status.json")

Alternately, instead of making the data available via a file, expose an HTTP endpoint so that external applications can retrieve the data with an HTTP GET request (you don't really need HTTP for this -- you could do the same thing with a simple socket endpoint -- but using HTTP often makes things more convenient because you can use something like curl for testing, and you can potentially expose different information at different paths).

The problem i had with your solution was that i got an error when the with statement ended and the temporary file could not be closed, because its name was changed and no file with its original name could be found:
"File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/tempfile.py", line 457, in close
unlink(self.name)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/out/tmpe5fx1tm2'

"I therefore changed the code so it would not delete the temporary file after exiting the with statement and at the same time save the file name of the temporary file to a variable so that i could call os.rename() outside of the with statement.

Now however if the file is opened through FTP-Filebrowser it is syntactically correct but sometimes wont load at all and is stuck with the file-loading screen.
The function SysFile.Open from the PLC programming IDE "Codesys" seems to ignore it whatsoever, because the read buffer still shows the aforementioned errors of the json file.

def write_to_json(data, filename):
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir= '/app/out', mode= 'w', delete= False) as fd:
json.dump(data, fd)
temp_file_name = fd.name
os.rename(temp_file_name, filename)

The code presented here runs without errors on python 3.12. There are no errors when exiting the with context.

Thank you so far your help and input:) I am currently tight on time, but when I have more time i'll look into the http variant. I think I am getting different results because the filesystem of the container is mounted on the host filesystem.

I tried it with http and that works! thank you so much for help again!
